# How can I loop AsyncAjaxRequest in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I need to make an ajax request every 10 seconds and update data on client side.

So, I've tried this way in my onModuleLoad():

```
while (true) {
    try {
        someService.initTable(new AsyncCallback<SomeObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SomeObject result) {
                        initData(numbersTable, result);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

But it goes to infinite loop.

I'd like to get something like this

```
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async calls in gwt execute immediately, and return "later". In your code, the while loop isn't waiting for anything, so you're calling initTable() many many times per second, hence the infinite loop.

Simply create a timer that executes every 10 seconds.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
              try {
                someService.initTable(new AsyncCallback<SomeObject>() {

                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(SomeObject result) {
                         initData(numbersTable, result);
                     }
                   });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }

};
timer.scheduleRepeating(10000);
```

Comment: Look great thank you! It's strange that I couldn't find this feature in docs.